# How to configure a grails plugin from another grails plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am trying to write a plugin which I can reuse in several grails applications.
The plugin should basically be a wrapper for the [spring security core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and the ldap plugin.

Which means it should contain:

- The domain classes for the user/roles
- The configuration for spring security (the mapping to these domain classes, some default URL access role configuration)

My problem is that i can't get the configuration inside my plugin working. I am confused by the examples I found so far: sometimes I read that the configuration should simply go to "Config.groovy" however [grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins) state that this file isn't part of a plugin in the end. In some examples it says that you have to put the configuration in any other .groovy file and wrap it with some identifier like so:

```
myConfigName {
    // normal config here
}
```

and then load it in the `doWithSpring` closure in the MyWrapperPlugin.groovy class via some slurper. However if i understand this correctly, this will only put the configuration in a `grails.plugin.mywrapper` namespace.

I could not find any example which tries to achieve the same thing (setting the configuraiton of a plugin inside another plugin) up to now.

Any examples/hints are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Grails Platform Core](http://grails.org/plugin/platform-core) that

> provides functionality for plugins to use to achieve greater integration with each other and with applications

The [Configuration API](http://grailsrocks.github.com/grails-platform-core/guide/configuration.html) it's what you are looking for. Just add the doWithConfig in your plugin descriptor file (*GrailsPlugin.groovy):

```
def doWithConfig = { config ->
  application {
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.active=true
    ...
  }
}
```